# Dynamic query string name in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a method like this which is called on click, 2 params are passed:

```
 selectOption(variantName, value) {
  this.$router.push({ query: { variantName: value } })
}
```

If I call selectOption with variantName = "size", and value ="small"

I want the url to be something like `/foo?size=small`

at the moment it is something like `?variantName=size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the key is dynamic you could wrap it by `[]` like :

```
 this.$router.push({ query: { [variantName]: value } })
```